# remove escape characters from char in c#

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem while retrieving nchar(2) from database and assigning to a char variable in c#. Below are the sample values:

**DB value:** S                **C# variable value** "S                             " 
**DB value:** null             **C# variable value** "\0                             "

I am retrieving with dynamic variable and after assigning it to a char variable, it is throwing an error. Do I need to trim first and remove the escape characters before assigning it to char variable or is there any standard functions to perform the task?

Comment: What is the error/exception you are getting ?, I think the result you are getting back is a string, and you can't assign it to a character type variable. You may try assigning the first character to your character type variable. Something like `youCharVariable = value[0];`

Comment: What is your database?  What are you using to read from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string dbValue = ...; // FROM DB!
string cValue = dbValue == null ? String.Empty : dbValue.Trim('\0').Trim();
```

You will get an empty string as result, for db's null values and also for empty strings...

Comment: My DB is SQL and retrieving using dapper. I may not be able to change the datatype from char to string. Thinking of efficient way to trim (retrieved values are having so many trialing spaces) the string  and assign it to the char variable.

Comment: Maybe you can use RegEx to trim any empty space, in an elegant and very fast way: new RegEx(@"\s*").Replace(text_to_clean, String.Empty)

Comment: thanks for your replies. I have tried it but problem I am facing was my char variable is of length 1. So again, I had to supply some empty char to initialize the variable. Tried with Habib's solution, it works well. Whatever the value, it takes first character but the problem is when I assign it to value in textbox, it is displaying weird � symbol if its null value. It is happening only in firefox not in IE.

Comment: My mistake I was assigning the char value directly to textbox. Now after converting to string, all worked well. Thanks again :-)